# Ubuntu Touch - SMS "Service Centre" Setting

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sms, bq, aquaris

In order to send SMSs, my service provider says I need to set the SMS "service centre". In Android, it's apparently on option underneath messages-->settings, but I don't see where to set it on Ubuntu Touch.  Under mobile-->carrier, there are only two options which can be manually set: Internet APN and MMS APN.  I had to set the internet APN manually in order to get mobile data.  But the SMS service centre is a phone number that needs to be set rather than a DNS name like the APN options.

Anyone else run into this issue?